# How to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, boolean, android-tablayout

I need to disable a particular tab in the tab layout, but the application crashes.

```
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()){
        case 0: tabLayout.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(true);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        case 2: tabLayout.getChildAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `switch` statement is missing a `break` after the `case`s.

Comment: i tried with break statement but its not working

Comment: Please, post the error message and any additional code needed to reproduce the problem. See also [MCVE].

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are simply missing `break` statements.

```
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()){
        case 0: tabLayout.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(true);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                break;
        case 2: tabLayout.getChildAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                break;
    }
}
```

The error seems to be that the `0` case falls through to try to `tabLayout.getChildAt(2)`, which is a null object reference.

Comment: i have try with break statement also but its showing error

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: Probably, then, the `tabLayout`'s 3rd child is not actually the 3rd tab. Have you confirmed that the problem does not occur if you remove case 2?

Comment: public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch (tab.getPosition()){
            case 0: tabLayout.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(true);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    break;

            case 1: viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    break;
            
            case 2: tabLayout.getChildAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    break;
        }
    }

Comment: same problem occur , i want first tab and third tab should be disable at first time

Comment: Sure. But I mean that `getChildAt(2)` is not necessarily the third tab, depending on layout. Have you tried removing the third tab first?